# MVC CORE SignalR send messages specific user only

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

Im using SignalR Core and ASPNET Core 2.2 and try to to send message to single user. for all user it's working fine.
Csharp code

```cs
[HubMethodName("SendMessageToUser")]
public Task DirectMessage(string user, string message)
{
  //eg.user = abcd@gmail.com
  return Clients.User(user).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
}
```

JS code

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (user, message) {
   var msg = message.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
   var encodedMsg = user + " says " + msg;
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.textContent = encodedMsg;
   document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: What is the string param `user` supposed to represent when an app hits the  `DirectMessage` Task endpoint? You should look into how SignalR maps and handles connected users/clients - [Docs - Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [Docs - Mapping Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections) look into the sections **Users in SignalR** and **IUserID provider**

Comment: `Clients.User` won't fetch you a client that you can use the `.SendAsync` on, unless you've set up authentication in the app, that will implement a user/principal provider for SignalR to use.

Comment: DirectMessage method is called, but ReceiveMessage is not Receiving message by user/ConnectionId

Comment: @alpeshvalvi did my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can send message to specific user using their connection id so
I need to create a hub like this. The GetConnectionId will return the connect id of that user when they connect to signalR hub

```cs
   public class ConnectionHub : Hub
        {
            public async Task Send(string userId)
            {
                var message = $"Send message to you with user id {userId}";
                await Clients.Client(userId).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
            }

            public string GetConnectionId()
            {
                return Context.ConnectionId;
            }
        }
```

Then in startup.cs

```cs
services.AddSignalR();
app.UseSignalR(routes =>
{
  routes.MapHub<ConnectionHub>("/connectionHub");
});
```

Then the client side code

```
(function () {
        var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/connectionHub").build();

        connection.start().then(function () {
            console.log("connected");

            connection.invoke('getConnectionId')
                .then(function (connectionId) {
                    sessionStorage.setItem('conectionId', connectionId);
                    // Send the connectionId to controller
                }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));;


        });

        $("#sendmessage").click(function () {
            var connectionId = sessionStorage.getItem('conectionId');
            connection.invoke("Send", connectionId);
        });

        connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        });

    })();
```

First I invoke getConnectionId in the hub to get user connection id then I can send message to specific user using their connection id.

Hope that help